# Insert character into String in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my batch file I have this line of code.

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=;/" %%i in ('findstr /v "#" clientsync.cfg') do echo %%l
```

My current output is

```
y/IC/draft
```

Is it possible to get an output like

```
y:/IC/draft
```

I would need to insert the : at the second position.
Tanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost done

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-4,* delims=;/" %%i in ('
    findstr /v "#" clientsync.cfg
') do echo %%l:/%%m
```

Just add a new token to separate the element you need and insert the colon and the slash consumed to get the new token

Answer (score 1):

first: put your output into a variable:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=;/" %%i in ('findstr /v "#" clientsync.cfg') do set output=%%l
```

second: use substrings to receate to your needs:

```
set output=%output:~0,1%:%output:~1%
```

`%output:~0,1%` takes a substring, starting from `0` (the first character) with length 1

`%output:~1%` takes a substring, starting from `1` (the second character) until the end of the string

reference: `set /?`

Comment: An additional reference from ss64.com, ["How-to: Extract part of a variable (substring)"](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html). This trick is not explicitly on that page, but maybe it should be. :)